# TYPE_SYM syntax error when running the mysql command to create or replace type

Tags: mysql

Here is my command:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TYPE DRIVINGSCHED_TYPE AS OBJECT
(
vehicle VARCHAR2(20),
datesched DATE,
starttime DATE,
endtime DATE
);
```

> ERROR: Line 1: syntax error, unexpected TYPE_SYM, expecting VIEW_SYM.
>   Statement skipped.

Comment: Could u plz let us know your mysql version

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of confusion that needs to be cleared up.

## MySQL

In MySQL, the SQL Clause `CREATE OR REPLACE` [***works with Views only***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-view.html)

You cannot create `CREATE OR REPLACE` any other types in MySQL (someone correct me if this is not so).

That's why `ERROR: Line 1: syntax error, unexpected TYPE_SYM, expecting VIEW_SYM. Statement skipped.` says `VIEW_SYM` is expected.

You also cannot create types with the above syntax in MySQL.

## PostgreSQL

[**You can create types in PostgreSQL, but there is no `CREATE OR REPLACE` syntax for creating types**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtype.html). You can use `CREATE OR REPLACE` for creating [functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createfunction.html) and [views](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createview.html), but not types.